# iOS error: 'message sent to dealllocated instance', when trying to change label

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, allocation

So the goal I am trying to achieve is that when I click on a button, I would like to change the text of a label. Following some tutorials online, and trying a myriad of alternative memory alloc/release, I still can't get past this error: *** -[HomeViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x4b4aa10

Here's my code:

In my app delegate:

```
   - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

        self.window.rootViewController = self.homeViewController;
        //[window addSubview:self.homeViewController.homeView];

        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

        return YES;
    }

- (void)dealloc {
    [homeViewController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Then in my HomeViewController.m:

```
@synthesize btnNewProject;
@synthesize btnOpenProject;
@synthesize label;

- (IBAction)newProject:(id)sender {
    NSString *text = @"We did it!";
    label.text = text;
    //[text release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    //self.homeView = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [label release];
    [btnOpenProject release];
    [btnNewProject release];
    //[homeView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

So the event fires and newProject is called, but I can't get past this crash. I've tried autoreleasing the controller, and some other things. Are there any glaring mistakes?

Thank you!

**UPDATE:**

So I am using IB. I have setup the connections properly, I think, from the HomeViewController (whose class I have set under Custom Class), to the buttons and label, and also the actions to the buttons.

One important detail is that I have a view on top of the view controller (and it's connected to the File's Owner), and the buttons and label are on top of the view in IB, but all the connections are through the HomeViewController - not sure if that should matter. I don't actually set the view anywhere in code (ie. in the App delegate where the controller is set up), but it is a variable within the HomeViewController, declared (without alloc) like the other variables (buttons and label):

```
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController {
    HomeView *homeView;

    UIButton *btnNewProject;
    UIButton *btnOpenProject;
    UILabel *label;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) HomeView *homeView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnNewProject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *btnOpenProject;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)openProject:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)newProject:(id)sender;

@end
```

Here is a screenshot of my connections:
[image]

Hmm... going to pick at the allocations a little more...

I have uploaded the project here:
http://devmu.com/transfer/NoteMap.zip

Comment: This error indicates that you are over-releasing an object.

Comment: The view controller wouldn't be released, so my first guess would be that you've connected the button's action to something other than the view controller.  My second guess would be that, based on the error message, you connected it to something with a method that includes an event argument, not just a sender argument.

Comment: You are leaking memory in `self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];`. Add an `autorelease` message to it. Do you use `performSelector:withObject:withObject:` anywhere in the project?

Comment: Hey Deepak.... should the [homeViewController release] in dealloc not do that? I tried putting autorelease in, but still get the error: self.homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];

I have uploaded the project here:
http://devmu.com/transfer/NoteMap.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I've downloaded and taken a look at your project.  You're getting mixed up with the view controllers being objects in Interface Builder.  It's an area the Apple documentation is lacking in, in my opinion.  You're better off with a book for learning this part.

The objects in Interface Builder are actual objects that are created, initialised, and placed into your `IBOutlet`s when the nib loads.  You have a `HomeViewController` in your nib.  But you are also allocating and initialising `HomeViewController` in code in your app delegate.  You only need to do one or the other.

I moved the view out of the view controller in Interface Builder, and deleted the view controller from your nib.  Once I renamed your nib to be `HomeViewController.xib` (as `HomeView.h` and `HomeView.m` seem to be leftovers and your nib corresponds to `HomeViewController`, the message showed up when the button was clicked.

Comment: Jim, "We did it!" ;) Thanks a lot for taking a look!

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing obviously wrong with your code. However, you need to check your connections in IB, which I'm assuming you are using. Make sure label and your button are both properly connected to what they need to be connected to.

Let's make sure you have the basics down.

Note: The "File's Owner" object's custom class should be set to HomeViewController. Make sure it says this under custom class.

Control click your "HomeViewController" (File's Owner) object and connect the btnNewProject outlet to the actual button; now control click the actual button connect the Touch Down event to the newProject: selector from the HomeViewController object.

If you do this everything **should be** fine using the code given. If not, there is something wrong with your code or project somewhere else. I hope this helps.

Comment: Also, unrelated to your problem I will point out that your line of code:

self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

can be rewritten as:

self.homeViewController = [[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeViewController" bundle:nil];

because if nil, this method looks for the nib file in the main bundle. (as shown in the UIViewController class reference.)

Comment: Hey Zach, thanks for the response. I updated my post (at the bottom) a little, but still having the same issue :\

Answer (score 1):

Try NSZombieEnabled environment variable and you will find the crash reason.

**UPDATE**

Yes if you change the method like this self.homeViewController = [[[HomeViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeView" bundle:nil] autorelease]; the app won't crash and it will show a blank white view. It seems you have created nib in some different way. What you need to do is just remove the view controller from the nib. There shoul be simple View and your buttons and bind that view to the first thing in interface builder that is called file's owner. I am posting a screenshot to clear understanding.

[image]

I'v made these changes and the application is working fine.

Comment: I have set that variable, and that is the message that it has given. Haven't had a chance to try Jim's suggestion yet, but it sounds like that should do the trick.

Comment: I have downloaded your code and there is no such nib named HomeViewController. That's why your application is crashing.

Comment: There was some renaming going on in my experimentation. It is actually referenced as HomeViewController.xib. Renaming HomeView.xib to HomeViewController.xib does not seem to change anything. Did you try this?